# Large file RSYNC / CP fails from Google Bucket to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rsync, cp, gsutil

I have a Google Ubuntu Instance successfully authenticated / connected to a Google Bucket and an Amazon S3 bucket.

I can copy / move / edit small files / folder in either bucket using a ubuntu instance and I can upload direct to the AWS web interface

I have about 4 files in the google bucket which I am trying to either RSYNC or GSUTIL CP from Google -> AWS

Small files go no problem, but anything over a few hundred megabytes fails with ServiceException 400.

Here are the command I have tried

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp -r gs://(source bucket)/ s3://(destination bucket)/
```

or

```
gsutil rsync -d -r gs://(source bucket) s3://(destination bucket)
```

Can anyone advise if they have had this issue before and the best way to push Google Bucket -> AWS without downloading / uploading.. i.e direct bucket to bucket

Answer (score 0):

From [rsync - Synchronize content of two buckets/directories  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync):

> If you are synchronizing a large amount of data between clouds you might consider setting up a Google Compute Engine account and running `gsutil` there. Since cross-provider `gsutil` data transfers flow through the machine where `gsutil` is running, doing this can make your transfer run significantly faster than running `gsutil` on your local workstation.

Thus, using this command actually *does* download then upload the data.

Since you say that you only have 4 files, it would probably be just as easy to download each of them from Google Cloud, then upload them to Amazon S3 with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).